# Incorrect upgrade header in connection to AWS IoT Core attempt response

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-iot

I am hosting a website on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, the website uses a spring boot backend and I am using NGINX for my reverse proxy. When the webserver starts up it attempts to make a connection to AWS IoT Core using the aws-iot-device-sdk-java library (I can't use AWS SDK as I need to subscribe to particular endpoints as well as publishing). However during the connection I recieve the following error:

`IOException: WebSocket Response header: Incorrect upgrade`

At first I thought the problem was that NGINX was stripping the Web Socket upgrade header out of the responses however I changed the proxy_pass url to point to a nonexistent endpoint and I was still getting the error, implying the responses were never passing through the proxy, I verified this with the access logs. I have tested this connection on the same web application running locally on my machine without a proxy and without SSL and it works fine so I am really stumpted as to what is going on here. Any help is appreciated.

NGINX Configuration for reference:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    31486;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server_tokens off;


    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" $connection_upgrade';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;


    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        #listen        80 default_server;

        #client_header_timeout 60;
        #client_body_timeout   60;
        #keepalive_timeout     60;
        #gzip                  off;
        #gzip_comp_level       4;
        #gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript      text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations

        server_name <REDACTED>; # managed by Certbot

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate <REDACTED>; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key <REDACTED>; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }

    server {
        if ($host = <REDACTED>) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen        80;
        server_name <REDACTED>
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    }
}
```

- I tried multiple different configurations of the NGINX setup before I realised that the responses might not be passing through it. However this is the only place where I can see the headers being lost due to the fact that is a [hop-to-hop](https://stackoverflow.com) header
- I have made sure that the NGINX configuration is running on the webserver using the eb engine logs.
- I am not currently using a load balancer